# Get ID of Table and store in Variable

Tags: mysql

I want to store the last updated row's id to a variable and then set a trigger to update some cells, the code for trigger:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE MYROW_ID INT;
DECLARE WITHDRAWAL DECIMAL(11,1);
DECLARE USERNAME VARCHAR(10);
SET MYROW_ID = SELECT id FROM withdrawals ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1;
SET WITHDRAWAL = SELECT withdrawal FROM withdrawals WHERE id = MYROW_ID;
SET USERNAME = SELECT username FROM withdrawals WHERE id = MYROW_ID;
UPDATE  `interests` SET  `totalincome` =  `totalincome` - 'WITHDRAWAL'
WHERE 'username' = 'USERNAME' AND 'status' = 1;
END
```

MySQL gives my error for 5th line, Am I assigning wrong data type i.e. `MYROW_ID`?
How can I store returned value from `SELECT into MYROW_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just put the statement between parentheses:

```
SET MYROW_ID = (SELECT id FROM withdrawals ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
SELECT id into MYROW_ID FROM withdrawals ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1;
```